# How to get user's list in firebase auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I am working on the vue-firebase application and want to know that how can I get the list of all registered users in firebase auth.
[image]

Comment: You will have to store uids in database.  Then run a loop on the node to get each ids.

Answer (score 1):

I am quite not sure if that is possible with one user try to get all the users, unless you are using firebase-admin. Though I have an idea how you can do that if you trying to get a list of added user being another user.
So, try to keep another list when a new user logs in, add the user details to a new node like userList.
And when ever you need them, call that node.
And incase you are using firebase-admin

```
admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
    .then(function(listUsersResult) {
```

will give the list.
Here's a reference. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users